# How to get the value of a specific field in a form in Django view function?

Tags: django

I am trying to achieve a load-up process in my system where the user will input the load amount and add it to a user's current load.

How can I get the amount entered in my view function?

Here's my function in my views.py

```
def LoadWallet(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.POST.get('user_id'))

    user_wallet = user.wallet

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_wallet = user_wallet+form.instance.load_amount
            User.objects.filter(id=pk).update(wallet=user_wallet)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user-details', args=[str(pk)]))
```

and the form in my template file

```
<form action="{% url 'load-wallet' user.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="load_amount">Load amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="load_amount" onkeyup="replaceNoneNumeric('load_amount')">
    <button type="submit" name="user_id" value="{{ user.id }}" class="btn btn-md btn-success" style="float: right; margin: 10px 5px;">Load</button>
</form>
```

Right now I tried this but it's returning "name 'LoadForm' is not defined". Should I declare the LoadForm first?

Is there a better way to implement this? Thank you!

Comment: You need to import the `LoadForm`...

Answer (score -1):

You might have an easier time using something like this, than `LoadForm`:

```
def LoadWallet(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.POST.get('user_id'))
    user_wallet = user.wallet
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = request.POST["user_id"]
        # Other logic here
    return ...
```

And in template

```
<form class="load-wallet" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="What is the user id?">
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: In my form the user will enter the load amount he wishes to add to current load. How can I get the inputted amount and add to the current load then update the current load?